# How to use fallback on picture tag - Safari Webp

Tags: html, safari, webp, fallback, picturefill

I'm using a code like:

```html
<picture class="image-holder">
    <source srcset="some_img.webp" media="screen and (max-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="some_img.webp" media="screen">
    <source srcset="some_img.jpg" media="screen and (max-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="some_img.jpg" media="screen">
    <img srcset="default_img.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

and what I hope is that when a browser like some versions of Safari doesn't support the Webp image format, fallback to the following source depending on media query and not directly to "default_img.jpg" .

But instead of that, what I get is a fallback direct to:

```html
<img srcset="default_img.jpg" alt="">
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which safari / os combo ? It works fine for me in MacOS Big Sur / Safari 14.0.3 Are you sure the paths are correct ?

Comment: Hi! the path are ok, it's working on Chrome, firefox, etc. is not working on safari 14.0.2, mac OS X catalina.

Comment: Do you have the code somewhere live to check it in action ?

Comment: I don't have a live place to hack it.
I found the issue.
Anyway, thanks Gabriele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I saw that adding the type, starts to work properly:

```html
<picture class="image-holder">
    <source srcset="some_img.webp" media="screen and (max-width: 1200px)" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="some_img.webp" media="screen" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="some_img.jpg" media="screen and (max-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="some_img.jpg" media="screen">
    <img srcset="default_img.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

if the MIME-type is not supported by the user agent the source element is skipped.

ex: if width < 1200px and the webp is unsupported, it fallback to:

```html
<source srcset="some_img.jpg" media="screen and (max-width: 1200px)">
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for posting the solution.